# Blender is creating weird artefacts when using a subdivision surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

I was working on a helmet model in Blender. I applied a subdivision surface modifier and I get weird spaces. What can I do to get rid of those spaces without deleting the subdivision surface modifier?

I attached some photos for reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please upload any images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: maybe try select all and W > Remove Doubles?

Comment: i'm sorry for the photos,I am new to this platform.Also the W > Remove Doubles works, thank you very much.